# LED light muliplexing

Tags: light

Is it possible to multiplex multiple power LED strings from a single driver unit to reduce heat generated?

For example I have two 20 Watt (100V @ 200mA) LED lamps.

If I include an electronic switch between driver and lamps, and switch them at an interval of 5 secs. will there be any problem?

Comment: Spehro Thanks. It was a Typo mistake. It is 100V@200mA. However, if 5 sec is quite long, we can make it say 1 sec. Does it improve the life. I am wondering if some body has already tried it, as heat generated is a too much

Comment: Your requirement is not fully clear. It appears that you trying to reduce the lamp temperature? Why are they too hot? Were they designed for 100 Volt operation? Can you run them at less current (about half current current) [:-)] and run both at once? That would save timing issues at changeover. You could multiplex them at above optically visible frequency and get the same power reduction.

Comment: Hi Russell, the requirement is very simple. I have two sets of 20 watt LED lamp. I want to switch on/off them alternatively for a period of 1 sec with a single driver, so that during 1 sec off time the LED junction gets cooled, and hence I improve the efficiency and life of LEDs

Comment: If you answered my questions you may end up with a better answer than you expected. | If your LEd junctions heat to full temperature in far less than 1 second then what you propose will at best double lifetime less any bad effects of thermal cycling. Depending on your heat sinking (intentional or fortuitous) you MAY be able to get 4x or 8x lifetime extension by running each string always on. If Tjunction at half current is 10C lower than at full current you get 2 x lifetime. ...

Comment: ... If Tjn_50% is say 20C lower than Tjn_100% you get 4 x lifetime. 20C drop happens if C/W thermal resistance of effective heatsink is worse than 2C/W. (As 10 Watt delta x 2C/W = 20C). This is very likely to be the case in practice. ) It's possible that by running 2 strips in parallel will get you  4x or 8x or more life extension over 1 strip at the same total current. ||
If you answer the above questions and describe the physical LED mounting setup more fully you may be surprised at the answer

Comment: I will put it other way round.I have two strips of 20watt LED lamps, and I have a single 20 watt LED driver circuit/LED Ballast. My intention is very simple, with a single driver board can I drive two loads by switching them at some time interval. In the meanwhile if I drive them above optically visible frequency can I effectively have 40watt output but the electrically I am consuming only 20 watt

Answer (score 2):

10V at 200mA is 2W, not 20W.

Yes, you could switch between two lamps like that, and if the circuitry is well-designed there should be no problem.

However, five seconds is about worst-case for causing thermal fatigue in the LED strings, so you may experience early failures (months rather than years). Or not, depending on the quality of the solder and other materials that are used.

Comment: Spehro Thanks. It was a Typo mistake. It is 100V@200mA. However, if 5 sec is quite long, we can make it say 1 sec. Does it improve the life. I am wondering if some body has already tried it, as heat generated is a too much